# I would like to know how can I know the reason that leaded to context switch

Tags: linux-kernel

Hello I would like to know how can I know the reason that leaded to context switch:
 1.The time slice of previous task has ended
 2.The previous task goes out for waiting
 3.A task with higher priority returns from waiting
 4.A task was created
 5.The task was ended
 6.The task yields CPU
Thank you

Comment: And ... what did you think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tracecmd and kernelshark.
See docs/screenshots: http://rostedt.homelinux.com/kernelshark/

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you'll get is the `schedstat` info, see Documentation/scheduler/sched-stats.txt.